# How to get a shortcut namespace into my xml document

Tags: xml, vb.net, serialization, namespaces, xml-serialization

Id like to create a xml document out of class using the xmlserializer functionallity. That works quite fine but one problem I cannot solve.

```
Public Class Request
End Class
```

I want to have the output

```
<test:Request
xmlns:test="http://test.de">
```

I managed to get the line

```
<Request 
xmlns:test="http://test.de">
```

but thats not what I wanted.

So could anyone help me how to add this shortcut <:test in front of my XML document?

Thanks in advance
radi5

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [XmlSerializerNamespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializernamespaces.aspx) when serializing your class and add the **XmlRoot** serialization attribute (pitfall: the *XmlType* attribute will not work)

```
<XmlRoot(Namespace := "http://test.de")> _
Public Class Request
End Class


Dim r As New Request()
Dim s As New XmlSerializer(GetType(Request))
Dim t As New StreamWriter(filename)
Dim ns As New XmlSerializerNamespaces()

ns.Add("test", "http://test.de")

s.Serialize(t, r, ns)
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks a lot. Your pitfall remark was my problem. I used XmlType and it was not working. radi5